# Actualizar el día de varias fechas registradas - CakePHP/Postgres

Tags: php, cakephp, postgresql-9.3

Soy nueva utilizando el framework CakePHP, en esta oportunidad me encuentro con el siguiente problema: Necesito modificar el día de varias fechas registradas en la bd (postgresql).

Pensé en extraer el día de la fecha que viene del formulario y armar la nueva fecha tomando apenas el año y mes de la fecha ya registrada, todo esto con `date_part()`, algo mas o menos así:

```
$fecha = $this->request->getData()['expired'];
$nuevaFecha =  "(date_part('year', expired) || '-' || date_part('month', expired) || '-' || date_part('day', '$fecha'::date))::date";

$fields += array('expired' => $nuevaFecha);

if ($this->Payments->updateAll($fields,$options)){
    $a = true;
    $rFlash ='Pagos actualizados con exito';
}
```

Probé el `query` completo resultante en pgAdmin y funciona bien... el problema (al menos eso creo ;-P) esta con cakePHP, el cual me arroja el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
Database Error
PDOException

Error: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "(date_part("year", expired) || - || date_part("month", expired) || - || date_part("day", 2018-08-05::datetime))::datetime"
```

Les agradezco de antemano toda la ayuda que me puedan prestar.

Comment: Se como resolver tu problema pero debes aclarar como tienes almacenada la fecha en la variable $fecha, es un string, una instancia de DateTime, que formato o forma tiene? Para poder responderte con seguridad

Comment: Hola! la variable ```$fecha``` obtiene el valor que viene del post como un string.. haciendo un ```var_dump``` de la misma resulta lo siguiente:  ```string(10) "2018-08-05" ```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes entonces hacer lo siguiente:

```
//Obtengo el dia con respecto a la fecha almacenada en la variable con el mismo nombre
$dia = substr($fecha,strrpos($fecha,'-')+1);

$nuevaFecha =  "(date_part('year', expired) || '-' || date_part('month', expired) || '-' || '$dia')";
```

Mira ver si esto funciona, espero que si :)

Comment: Hola Dariel, continua dando el mismo error:  ```Error: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "(date_part('year', expired) || '-' || date_part('month', expired) || '-' || '05')" ```

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas, creo que tuve ese mismo error hace dos años, pero en el caso de cakephp, creo que al revisar mi anterior pregunta (yo usaba sin framework) creo que es el formato del datetime, ahora con cakephp; viendo este [manual del date & time en inglés](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html)

la forma correcta del formato sería asi como ejemplo lo que se ha visto en el manual;

```
$date = new Date('2015-06-15'); // Outputs 2015-06-15 00:00:00
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

por cierto bienvenida a la comunidad de stackoverflow en español!